# UIBarButtonItem jumps on back gesture when using custom font

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I've problem with customising `UIBarButtonItem` title text attributes. When I use custom font (Clear Sans by Intel) it jumps on back gesture, when popping the view controller. Have you met the same problem?

Code to set attributes is:

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
    NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"ClearSans" size:17.0f],
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: kRedColor
} forState: UIControlStateNormal];`

You can find the gif example here. Watch the Edit button: [image: button jump]

Comment: Do you have some code in `viewDidAppear` which might trigger that? If so, it might make sense to move it to `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: That's it. It was necessary to set `rightBarButtonItem` in `viewDidLoad` not in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Glad that it worked :-) - I added my comment as an answer, so the question has an answer. Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have some code in `viewDidAppear` which might trigger that? If so, it might make sense to move it to `viewWillAppear`.